# Using Express.js, how can I send a file on any request?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to send `index.html` on any get request.

Code:

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html'));
  res.end();
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Server started on port 8000'));
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist', 'index.html'));
  res.end();
});
```

to

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', {root: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'dist')});
    res.end();
});
```

Comment: You don't have to add a slash when you defining your route with a star.

Answer (score 2):

A nice technique you can use here is to store the html page in the ram so your system doesn't have to read the file every time a request is made. I suggest you to use the fs library. Try the following.

```
import express from 'express';
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express();

var indexPage = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/PATH_TO/index.html', 'utf8')

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
   return res.send(indexPage)
})

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Server started on port 8000'));
```

With your current solution you try to read the file for every request. By doing the above you will save a lot of CPU power and provide a much faster result.

Comment: This means however the file would stay in the memory forever, be careful if you have a large file and small memory